# How to hide MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration slider from locked screen and Control Center?

Tags: ios, swift, controls, avplayer

I'm working on online radio player and need some help.
When I set `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo` I have title, controls and playback duration slider. I don't need this slider because I have no info about playback duration and moreover it is not a very good looking control.
Can somebody prompt me how to hide playback duration slider?
And one more question: since the app is online radio player, the user have no ability to forward or rewind the playback, so I want to hide this controls from locked screen and Control Center either.
By the way I'm using Swift.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In case its a live stream you can set the `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyIsLiveStream` property `true`. Instead of the slider a 'LIVE' label will be displayed.

Comment: MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo =
 [MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyIsLiveStream: true]

Answer (score 0):

To hide the forward and rewind buttons, you disable the relevant commands in `MPRemoteCommandCenter`.  Here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28925369.

I wish I knew how to hide the playback slider.  I posted [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31751974/how-to-hide-the-playback-slider-in-the-ios-control-center) before finding yours.

Comment: if the value for the duration is 0, the slider is hidden

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a way to hide the playback duration slier too and couldn't find any. Then I played a radio from Apple Music app and when I locked the screen I could see the duration slider. So either there is no way to remove it or Apple "forgot" to remove it on their own Music app.

Answer (score 0):

```
[songInfo setObject:@0 forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
[playingInfoCenter setNowPlayingInfo:songInfo];
```

When you set MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration to 0, the slider is gone.

Comment: Tried hiding it, does not work.

Comment: This was 4 years ago, it may have changed behavior since I made this answer.