# How to hide the playback slider in the iOS Control Center?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In a streaming music app, it doesn't make sense to display the playback slider in the Control Center or on the lock screen.  How can I hide the slider?

I use Xamarin, but any code snippets in Obj-C or Swift would be welcomed.

To hide the backwards and forwards buttons, I disabled commands on [MPRemoteCommandCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPRemoteCommandCenter_Ref/).  However, I've had no luck with hiding the slider with this technique.

[image: Playback slider in iOS Command Center]