# How to custom MPNowPlayingInfoCenter Button?

Tags: ios, ios7, mpnowplayinginfocenter, control-center

I would like Control Center (via MPNowPlayingInfoCenter) to show the  MPFeedbackCommand controls that Apple shows with podcasts, like so:
![enter image description here][1]

how can I do that, [likeCommand setLocalizedTitle:@" emotion I love it"];I mean that added a love emotion to the string. And how to change the color of "x".Thanks for your help!

Because I can't post picture,so look at this link:
[Is there a public way to force MPNowPlayingInfoCenter to show podcast controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591156/is-there-a-public-way-to-force-mpnowplayinginfocenter-to-show-podcast-controls)