# Is it possible to hide all the controls when screen is locked? - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-audio, screen-lock

I want to hide all the controls on the locked screen when an app is playing in the background. However, I want the audio related information to be displayed all the time.

I read about MPRemoteCommandCenter but we can't implement the below code because when you try to disable all then the screen starts showing 3 controls (toggle button, next track, previous track)

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter *rcc = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
[[rcc skipForwardCommand] setEnabled:NO];
[[rcc skipBackwardCommand] setEnabled:NO];
[[rcc nextTrackCommand] setEnabled:NO];
[[rcc previousTrackCommand] setEnabled:NO];
[[rcc skipForwardCommand] setEnabled:NO];
[[rcc skipBackwardCommand] setEnabled:NO];
rcc.playCommand.enabled = NO;
rcc.pauseCommand.enabled = NO;
```

Is there any other way to achieve what I am expecting?
Currently play pause button is visible.
[image]

EDIT: My question is not a duplicate of [How to disable all the MPRemoteCommand objects from MPRemoteCommandCenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993801/how-to-disable-all-the-mpremotecommand-objects-from-mpremotecommandcenter) because I want to hide. The answer given on the other question disables the controls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable all the MPRemoteCommand objects from MPRemoteCommandCenter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993801/how-to-disable-all-the-mpremotecommand-objects-from-mpremotecommandcenter)

Comment: My question is not a duplicate of How to disable all the MPRemoteCommand objects from MPRemoteCommandCenter because I want to hide. The answer given on the other question disables the controls.

Comment: How is disabling controls different from hiding them?

Comment: @stek29 Disabled controls can be visible, but greyed out  for example. Hidden controls are not visible.

Comment: @AsthaGupta I highly doubt it is possible, sadly.