# Remove Actions From MPRemoteCommandCenter

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, mpremotecommandcenter

I have 2 `ViewControllers` which each play a diffrent `AVAudioPlayer`. Each one needs a diffrent set of commands for the `MPRemoteCommandCenter`. Each ViewController has something like this:

```
let remoteCommandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter().shared

func refreshCommandCenterButtons() {
        remoteCommandCenter.previousTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
        remoteCommandCenter.nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
        remoteCommandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
        remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
        remoteCommandCenter.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.playButtonTapped))
        remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pauseButtonTapped))
        remoteCommandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.nextButtonTapped))
        remoteCommandCenter.previousTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.previousButtonTapped))
        remoteCommandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.playPauseAction))     
    }



override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

 refreshCommandCenterButtons()

}
```

Whenever a user plays a song from `FirstViewController`, and then navigate to the `SecondViewController`, the `FirstViewContoller's` audioPlayer pauses. The problem is that once a user navigates from `FirstViewController` to the Second, and presses the play button on the Second, it plays both audioPlayers.

I tried adding this to the `refreshCommandCenterButtons()` function. This would be in the `SecondViewController`:

```
remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand.removeTarget(#selector(FirstViewController().pauseButtonPressed))
remoteCommandCenter.playCommand.removeTarget(#selector(FirstViewController().playButtonPressed))
remoteCommandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.removeTarget(#selector(FirstViewController().playPauseTapped))
```

But nothing changed. What do I do? Thanks for the help!

Comment: ** [Refer this link ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39081521/7776881) to solve this issue

Comment: only 
self.commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.isEnabled = false
                                self.commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = false
                                self.commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = false
                                self.commandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = false

that working