# How to add seek buttons on iOS lock screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpnowplayinginfocenter

How to setup MPRemoteCommandCenter/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter to add seek buttons? Result that I want to achieve is on the screenshot.
[image: Seek buttons should look like]
I have already added this code:

```
[[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].seekForwardCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent * _Nonnull event) {
    [weakSelf rewindForward];

    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}];
[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].seekForwardCommand.enabled = YES;

[[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].seekBackwardCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent * _Nonnull event) {
    [weakSelf rewindBackward];

    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}];
[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].seekBackwardCommand.enabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would also need to set `preferredIntervals` as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24818340/1514970.

Comment: Great! @waywalker, Thanks a lot.